# Share content into LinkedIn Company Page

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

This may be a n00b question, but I can't deduce from the API documentation: Is it possible to share content (from, say, a Website that may have an interesting article about something) TO a LinkedIn Company Page? It appears that you can share FROM a Company Page via the API, but I want to know if you can post, say, a link/URL to the Company Page.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can share on behalf of a company that you are an administrator of in LinkedIn via the API.  The documentation is available here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_share

In a nutshell, you POST the following payload to this endpoint:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/shares?format=json

<share>   
  <visibility>
    <code>anyone</code>
  </visibility>   
  <comment>There are a lot of great career opportunities here!</comment> 
</share>
```

Comment: Let me know if I'm wrong but you shouldn't add 'format=json' in the url as you are passing data in XML.